# Checking for new data arrival from a RSS feed

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I made a RSS reader app for android and it gets the latest news from a RSS feed. I want to show a Notification to the user when a news is published to the website or the RSS feed. How can I check for new data?

Comment: Probably you will have to create background service that periodically
check for updates.

Comment: @Yupi can you please guide me a little because I am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something which is called polling. Actually many rss reader apps using polling technique in which their
service wakes up at a regular interval to contact a server to see if new data needs to be processed.
This means that the application needs to wake up to look for new data even if none is
available to be processed. Read about `IntentService` and `AlarmManager`. Basically you can create `AlarmManager` which is going to start every amount of time that you want for example every hour. Than you can start a service which is going to check is new data available. If it is new data for processed available raise a notification on user phone. Set `AlarmManager` to fires up again for an hour and the service should shutt down itself. Hope this will help.